# log4net custom properties not working with multi-threaded app

Tags: c#, log4net

I have an app that is using the log4net AdoNetAppender (DB appender) to write my logs to the database. It is writing the records to the DB, but the custom fields are all NULL.  They work fine using the same code in my unit tests, but not when they are called when the application is running.  It is a multi-threaded application that processes messages off of a message queue.

Is there any known issues (that anyone is aware of) regarding custom properties for the DB appender with multi-threaded applications? That is my only guess as to why they are not working when the app is spun up because I can't reproduce in unit tests, etc.

The default log4net fields come through fine.

I am setting the custom property values in a Singleton:

```
   public sealed class Logger
    {
        private static readonly Logger instance = new Logger();
        public static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);


        /// <summary>
        /// Static constructor which sets the properties for the database logging using log4net. This enables analysts to view the log events
        /// inside the database as well as in the local application log file. 
        /// </summary>
        static Logger()
        {
            GlobalContext.Properties["Application"] = "MyApp";
            GlobalContext.Properties["ApplicationVersion"] = Utility.GetApplicationVersion();
            var windowsHost = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(windowsHost))
                LogicalThreadContext.Properties["Host"] = windowsHost;
            //ThreadContext.Properties["LogTime"] = DateTime.Now;
            var windowsIdentity = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
            if (windowsIdentity != null)
                GlobalContext.Properties["CreatedBy"] = windowsIdentity.Name;
        }

        private Logger()
        {

        }

        public static Logger Instance
        {
            get { return instance; }
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

Found this going to try and add additional log4net debugging.

```
http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html#internalDebug
```

Not seeing any errors in log4nets internal logs so still unclear about what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out.  It was how we were trying to set the custom properties globally.  I instead set the properties on app startup prior to any of my instances binding to the queue and processing messages.  That seemed to do it....not sure why I didn't think of that in the beginning.  Just used the log4net GlobalContext and worked like a charm.

--S